# Is the equation based on copula function right?

Tags: probability

Is the equation based on copula function right?
$$ \int_q^1\int_p^1 (C(p,q)+1) \, dC(u,v) = (C(p,q)+1)(1-p-q+C(p,q)) $$
where p and q are two constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for a 2-copula,

$$\int_q^1\int_p^1 (C(p,q)+1) \, dC(u,v) = (C(p,q)+1)\int_q^1\int_p^1 \, dC(u,v)\\=[C(p,q)+1][C(1,1)-C(p,1)-C(1,q)+C(p,q)]\\=[C(p,q)+1][1-p-q+C(p,q)]$$